# Using two vectors to loop through code to generate one xlsx output using R

Tags: r, excel, loops

I have data in several excel databases which I want to combine into one excel with adjusted information. Unique identifiers are the ALM naming of the excel files to be loaded, and Boog_ID in an big Excel database.

I have the next code written:

```
#Import section_id's and corresponding ALM's
section_ids <- read.csv2("section_ids.csv", colClasses = "character")

## Repeat all below for all sections
for (i in section_ids$alm) {
  for (j in section_ids$boog_id) {

#Import excel using "Import dataset" 
hor <- read_xlsx(paste("ALM_", i,".xlsx", sep = ""), 1)
ver <- read_xlsx(paste("ALM_", i,".xlsx", sep = ""), 2)
add_complete <- read_xlsx("curve_information_combined.xlsx")

#Extract correct additional information
add <- filter(add_complete, BoogID == j)

## A bunch of code to generate a dataframe named "combined"  to generate a dataframe per section_id.
## This code works flawless and is therefore left out of this example

#Export as xlsx
write.xlsx(combined, "road_characteristics.xlsx", row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
  }
}
```

I was hoping to generate an excel file containing all the information of all the section_id's. However, the loop seems stuck after the first iteration, generating an excel only containing information about the first curve_id. 
Furthermore, i has not been updated to the second value in section_ids$alm, but j has updated to the second value in section_ids$boog_id.

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the loop continue? Perhaps a basic mistake in the for-loop? I've searched the web, but haven't found a good answer.

Comment: Hello Johan. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question.  As currently written, there isn't enough information in your question for someone to figure out why the loops aren't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As Len mentioned, I'll try and give a reproducible example, but I'm not sure about this... #noob

```
alm <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
section_id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
section_ids <- data.frame(alm, section_id)                          

for (i in section_ids$alm) {
  for (j in section_ids$boog_id) {

#some code
example <- i
test <- j
combined <- merge(example, test)

#Export as xlsx
write.xlsx(combined, "road_characteristics.xlsx", row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
  }
}
```